# Email signature becomes attachment when replied from Gmail

Tags: email, html-email, email-attachments

I have a new signature and I use Outlook 2003 to send out my emails. The graphics within are sourced from a server. The email+signature look fine, but when somebody using Gmail replies to me, the graphics within the email become attachments for them.

Previous answers suggest having the graphic on a web server, but I do this already.

One possible fix I have seen is using moz-do-not-send="true" ...but that is only for Mozilla it seems, is there not a global alternative or another fix I could use?

Many thanks.

```
     <span><a href="http://www.website.co.uk" target="_blank" ><img src="http://www.website.co.uk/allowed/images/logo.jpg" border="0" hspace="10" /></a></span>
```

Comment: I think this is effectively the same problem? 
0) I use gmail on web
1) I receive an email from someone with signature including hosted graphics (original email does not have attachments)
2) when i reply to them from gmail, their signature graphics turn into attachments

Answer (score 0):

I have been messing with this for a while now and I may have found a fix.

First, I created a complete HTML file.

```
<table cellPadding="0" cellSpacing="0">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td style="vertical-align:top"></td>
        <td>
            <div><font size="4">Name</font></div>
            <div>Title</div>
            <div><span style="margin-right:8px"><a href="tel:phonenumber">phone</a></span></div>
            <div><span style="margin-right:8px"><a style="color:blue" href="mailto:email">email</a></span></div>
            <div><span style="margin-right:8px">address</span></div>
            <div style="padding: 0 0em 2em 0;">
                <a href="https://facebook.com" title="Facebook"><img src="http://CDN/Facebook.jpg?7" alt="Facebook" /></a>
                <a href="https://twitter.com/" title="Twitter"><img src="http://CDN/Twitter.jpg?5" alt="Twitter" /></a>
                <a href="https://instagram.com/" title="Twitter"><img src="http://CDN/Instagram.jpg?3" alt="Instagram" /></a>
                <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/" title="LinkedIn"><img src="http://CDN/Linkedin.jpg?2" alt="LinkedIn" /></a>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

As you can see, I added a `?` and then a number after my image source. So far, in two days of testing from Outlook (I admit, I am using the web interface and have yet to test from the app) to Gmail then replying back to Outlook - all of my replies send the signature as they should.

I opened my HTML and copy and pasted the signature into Outlook.

Fingers crossed this continues to work and hopefully this helps someone else.

Comment: update: it does not work from the app. the application is converting the image to something other than the actual URL where the image is hosted.